# Sound indicator broken after 12.10 update (shows 3 dashes), sound settings shows no devices

Tags: sound, indicator, settings

Im using Ubuntu 12.10 and my sound has worked great so far.
After installing an update I get the same problem described here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/97217/sound-broken-after-installing-updates-no-hardware-present-but-some-programs-p)

3 dashes on the indicator, sound settings shows no devices, i cannot set master volume using hotkeys, or the indicator. Banshee and some other apps still play sound.

`pidof pulseaudio`  brings back nothing

Typing `pulseaudio` in the terminal brings:

```
E: [pulseaudio] module-ladspa-sink.c: Master sink not found
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-ladspa-sink" (argument: "sink_name=ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq control=2.0,1.3,0.7,0.0,-1.3,-2.0,-2.3,-2.6,-1.6,-1.0,0.0,0.7,1.0,1.3,2.3"): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

i don't know what to do now.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: no. I got a new laptop. The old one still has that problem.